# Google PHP API Offline Access Issue

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I am trying to use Google PHP API to sream contents from Google plus. I was able to get the refresh token. But when I tried to get access token using that refresh token, its returning the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in /var/www/social-media-test/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php:242 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/social-media-test/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php(281): apiOAuth2->refreshToken('MY-REFRESH-TOKEN-HERE') #1 /var/www/social-media-test/google-api-php-client/examples/plus/p.php(19): apiClient->refreshToken('MY-REFRESH-TOKEN-HERE') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/social-media-test/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php on line 242

MY code is as shown below.

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
$client->setClientId('client-id');
$client->setClientSecret('secret-key');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/index.php/main');
$client->setDeveloperKey('dev-key');
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

$client->refreshToken('MY-REFRESH-TOKEN');
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot this:

```
$client->setScopes(array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
));
```

ref: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth#Scope